# Permutations problem.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Today I did permutations and I read about this theorem:

> *"The number of permutations of $n$ objects, where $p$ objects are of the same kind and rest are all different $= n!/p!$"*

Now this formula is certainly for using up the maximum spaces possible to arrange things.

Like, the word $SCHOOL$ when solved for, by this formula, would give me $6!/2! = 360$. This would give me number of all 5 letter words possible without repetition, from the letters of $SCHOOL$ if I'm not wrong. I was wondering if there is a formula using which, I can find the number of words without repetition, with as many letters as I want.

To put it another way, how can I find out the number of 3-letter words that can be formed from $SCHOOL$ without any repetition? A general formula maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by without repetition? Do you wish to form $3$-letter words selected without repetition from the letters of the set $\{S, C, H, O, L\}$ or selected without repetition from the letters of the multiset $\{1 \cdot S, 1 \cdot C, 1 \cdot H, 2 \cdot O, 1 \cdot L\}$, that is, from all six of the letters  of the word SCHOOL?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig The first one.

Comment: So both $LOO$ and $LOL$ are not allowed? Then it's just $5\cdot 4\cdot 3 = 5!/(5-3)!$.

Comment: @Christoph Can I generalize it in terms of p and n like the theorem stated above?

Comment: Given your interpretation of the problem, the number of possible arrangements of $k$ of the $n$ distinct letters is $P(n, k) = \binom{n}{k}k! = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an alphabet $\Sigma = \{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ of $n$ different symbols and you want to form words of length $k$ with each symbol appearing at most once, the number of these is
$$
n\cdot (n-1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (n-k+1) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = \binom{n}{k} k!.
$$
In your example the alphabet is $\Sigma = \{\mathrm S,\mathrm C,\mathrm H,\mathrm O,\mathrm L\}$ so $n=5$ and $k=3$.